# PDF.js: how to save the HTML5 code?

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

I use Chrome [PDF renderer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm) based on PDF.js. The PDF is displayed, but **how to save the html5 code ?**

(sadly, the tab's source display some strange code which is clearly not HTML5, so where is my HTML5 code ?)

Comment: What do you mean by "Save the HTML5 code"?

Comment: If i understood well pdf.js convert pdf stuffs into html5 elements.